# Increase screen resolution with VGA Intel GMA 3150

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, resolution, screen

is there any way to increase the aspect ratio resolution netbook with intel GMA 3150 chipset from 1024x600 to be larger than 1280? I use Ubuntu Precise beta 2

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit about your configuration so that we can answer?
Your screen native resolution. and could you provide the output of these commands:
xrandr -q 
&&
lspci | grep VGA

Comment: I use netbook 10.1, and standar resolution 1024x600. and I want to raise to 1280x750 or above, if it could?

this is output script for: 
~$ xrandr -q && lspci | grep VGA –
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 222mm x 125mm
   1024x600       60.0*+
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
grep: –: No such file or directory

Comment: Sounds like the maximum and native resolution of your netbook screen is 1024x600. The screen you have does not support higher resolutions. If you try to force it, you may damage it. And to be sure, please provide me with the name and model of your netbook (e.g: Emachines or Acer Netbook 10.1).

Comment: my Netbook is Axioo Pico PJM A615 see these page: [link](http://axiooworld.com/region/index.php?act=product&goto=detil&id=PICO&type=PJM&hal=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I now have learned that the screen you have is manufactured to support a **maximum of 1024 x 600** as resolution. It's physically impossible to force it to handle a higher resolution whatever the OS.
In another hand, to feel more comfortable, reduce the desktop font and launcher icon size. (Install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/install-ubuntu-tweak-on-ubuntu-new.html) for example:  )

[image: Ubuntu Tweak Font Settings]

[image: Ubuntu Tweak Unity Settings]

---

And if you're not afraid to damage your screen, you can upscale its resolution to 1280 or even higher using the **NewRez** Script ( A script that uses the XRANDR utility for intel graphics). Download and instruction through here:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/set-your-screen-resolution-higher-than-you-should-with-newrez/

Comment: thanks for the help. actually when I using ubuntu maverick, I can change the size to 1280x750 with a nautilus script "newrez" but somehow since ubuntu uses gtk-3 script was not working well.

Answer (score 0):

xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --scale 1x1.28

works to a degree =)